# How do I set my Flowplayer to transparent?

Tags: transparent, flowplayer

I'm using this code for my player:

```
    <div class="video">
            <div id="player">
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.10.min.js"></script> 
                                            <a href="http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/20051210-w50s.flv" style="display:block;width:640px;height:480px" id="myAlternativeContent"></a> 
                    <script>
                        flowplayer("myAlternativeContent", { 
                             src:"/flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.11.swf", 
                             wmode: 'transparent',
                             key: '#$52177209b15c5b2bf56'
                             },
                             {
                          clip:  {
                              autoPlay: false,
                              autoBuffering: true,
                              url: 'http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/20051210-w50s.flv',
                              provider: 'lighttpd'
                          },
                          plugins: {
                                lighttpd: {
                                    url: "/flowplayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.9.swf"
                                }
                            }
                        });
                                            </script>
    <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->


                                <!-- id="player" --></div>
```

However the player doesn't seem to be transparent. When I add in player ads and they don't show. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Hint: You should not include your key on a public site like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object parameters to set the `wmode` property of the player as you've done, but it have to be the second parameter, including the `src` property to pass in the player swf (that is your 2nd parameter).

http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/wmode.html:

```
flowplayer("player", {
    src:"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf",
    wmode: "opaque" // This allows the HTML to hide the flash content
},
{
    clip: {
        url: 'http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv'
    }
});
```

Comment: I did this, but with no luck. See above, I changed the code in the question.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the flowplayer sopport team? Since you have a paid license, you have support rights, not?

Comment: They charge 30 euros per support issue. This is what I'm trying to avoid.